# Как сделать slick slider отзывчивым?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, slick.js

При верстке возник вопрос, почему при изменении ширины окна в панели разработчика браузера slic slider не изменяет ширину и столбцы а также стрелки переключения слайдов вылазют за окно собственно браузера. Одним словом сейчас он не responsive. При этом адаптив работает то есть вот эта штука:

```
responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1280,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
```

Вот такой собственно не респонсив эффект :

[image: Вот такой собственно не респонсив эффект]

**НTML слайдера:**

```
<div class="team__slider">
    <div class="team__card card">
        <div class="team__card-img-wrap card__img-wrap">
            <img class="team__card-img card_img" src="img/team/card_01.jpeg" alt="John">
        </div>
        <div class="team__card-text-wrap card__text-wrap">
            <h1 class="team__card-title card_title column-price__title-item">John Doe</h1>
            <p class="team__card-subtitle-1 card_subtitle-1">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
            <p class="team__card-subtitle-2 card_subtitle-2 subtitle-type-1">Harvard University</p>
        </div>
        <div class="team__card-links-wrap card-links-wrap">
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </div>                    
        <p class="team__card-button-wrap card__button-wrap"><button class="team__card-button card__button column-price__button">Contact</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="team__card card">
        <div class="team__card-img-wrap card__img-wrap">
            <img class="team__card-img card_img" src="img/team/card_02.jpg" alt="John">
        </div>
        <div class="team__card-text-wrap card__text-wrap">
            <h1 class="team__card-title card_title column-price__title-item">David Jons</h1>
            <p class="team__card-subtitle-1 card_subtitle-1">Team Lead</p>
            <p class="team__card-subtitle-2 card_subtitle-2 subtitle-type-1">London University</p>
        </div>
        <div class="team__card-links-wrap card-links-wrap">
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </div>                    
        <p class="team__card-button-wrap card__button-wrap"><button class="team__card-button card__button column-price__button">Contact</button></p>
    </div>
    <div class="team__card card">
        <div class="team__card-img-wrap card__img-wrap">
            <img class="team__card-img card_img" src="img/team/card_03.jpg" alt="John">
        </div>
        <div class="team__card-text-wrap card__text-wrap">
            <h1 class="team__card-title card_title column-price__title-item">Artem Kravetz</h1>
            <p class="team__card-subtitle-1 card_subtitle-1">PR Manager</p>
            <p class="team__card-subtitle-2 card_subtitle-2 subtitle-type-1">Kiev University</p>
        </div>
        <div class="team__card-links-wrap card-links-wrap">
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </div>                    
        <p class="team__card-button-wrap card__button-wrap"><button class="team__card-button card__button">Contact</button></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS слайдера :**

```
    .team__slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}
.team__card {
    flex: 30.33333% 0 0;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: 0 20px;
}
.team__card-img {
    /* width: 300px;
    height: 300px; */
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 50%; */
    height: 275px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.card-links-wrap {
    display: flex;
    margin: 40px auto 40px auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 64%;
}
.team__card-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: black;
}
.team__card-link:hover {
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg) translate(0, -10px);
}
.team__card-link:nth-child(1):hover {
    background: #f082ac;
}
.team__card-link:nth-child(2):hover {
    background: #0084b4;
}
.team__card-link:nth-child(3):hover {
    background: #C32AA3;
}
.team__card-link:nth-child(4):hover {
    background: #3b5998;
}
.team__card-link:hover.team__card-link .fa {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.team__card-link .fa {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 22px;
}
.card__link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.card__button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.team__card-title {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-top: 24px;
    font-size: 29px;
}
.team__card-subtitle-1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "Open Sans Semibold";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #6a6a6a;
    text-align: center;
}
.team__card-subtitle-2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.team__card-button-wrap {
    margin: 0;
}
.team__card-button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    background: #999999;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "Open Sans Semibold";
}
.team__card-button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

**JS слайдера :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.team__slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    // autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    dots: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    // infinite: false,

    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1280,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]

  });
});
```

Comment: у тебя jQuery подключень?

Comment: Нет ли блока выше, который не дает родительному блоку слайдера принять нужную ширину?

Comment: Armen jqurey подключен )  вот так :<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Jquery подключен, нету родттельского блока который бы ограничивал уменьшение ширины

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает:

```js
$('.team__slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  // autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  dots: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  // infinite: false,

  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1280,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.team__slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}

.team__card {
  flex: 30.33333% 0 0;
  background: #d8d8d8;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.team__card-img {
  /* width: 300px;
    height: 300px; */
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 50%; */
  height: 275px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-links-wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px auto 40px auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 64%;
}

.team__card-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: black;
}

.team__card-link:hover {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg) translate(0, -10px);
}

.team__card-link:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: #f082ac;
}

.team__card-link:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: #0084b4;
}

.team__card-link:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: #C32AA3;
}

.team__card-link:nth-child(4):hover {
  background: #3b5998;
}

.team__card-link:hover.team__card-link .fa {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.team__card-link .fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card__button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.team__card-title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 24px;
  font-size: 29px;
}

.team__card-subtitle-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Open Sans Semibold";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #6a6a6a;
  text-align: center;
}

.team__card-subtitle-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.team__card-button-wrap {
  margin: 0;
}

.team__card-button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  background: #999999;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Open Sans Semibold";
}

.team__card-button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="team__slider">
  <div class="team__card card">
    <div class="team__card-img-wrap card__img-wrap">
      <img class="team__card-img card_img" src="img/team/card_01.jpeg" alt="John">
    </div>
    <div class="team__card-text-wrap card__text-wrap">
      <h1 class="team__card-title card_title column-price__title-item">John Doe</h1>
      <p class="team__card-subtitle-1 card_subtitle-1">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
      <p class="team__card-subtitle-2 card_subtitle-2 subtitle-type-1">Harvard University</p>
    </div>
    <div class="team__card-links-wrap card-links-wrap">
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </div>
    <p class="team__card-button-wrap card__button-wrap"><button class="team__card-button card__button column-price__button">Contact</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="team__card card">
    <div class="team__card-img-wrap card__img-wrap">
      <img class="team__card-img card_img" src="img/team/card_02.jpg" alt="John">
    </div>
    <div class="team__card-text-wrap card__text-wrap">
      <h1 class="team__card-title card_title column-price__title-item">David Jons</h1>
      <p class="team__card-subtitle-1 card_subtitle-1">Team Lead</p>
      <p class="team__card-subtitle-2 card_subtitle-2 subtitle-type-1">London University</p>
    </div>
    <div class="team__card-links-wrap card-links-wrap">
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </div>
    <p class="team__card-button-wrap card__button-wrap"><button class="team__card-button card__button column-price__button">Contact</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="team__card card">
    <div class="team__card-img-wrap card__img-wrap">
      <img class="team__card-img card_img" src="img/team/card_03.jpg" alt="John">
    </div>
    <div class="team__card-text-wrap card__text-wrap">
      <h1 class="team__card-title card_title column-price__title-item">Artem Kravetz</h1>
      <p class="team__card-subtitle-1 card_subtitle-1">PR Manager</p>
      <p class="team__card-subtitle-2 card_subtitle-2 subtitle-type-1">Kiev University</p>
    </div>
    <div class="team__card-links-wrap card-links-wrap">
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a class="team__card-link card__link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </div>
    <p class="team__card-button-wrap card__button-wrap"><button class="team__card-button card__button">Contact</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, за правильный ответ. У меня этот вопрос решился таким образом что я подключил swiper слайдер, и разместил его html код непосредственно в родительском блоке, как мне товарищ выше в коментариях советовал -
(Нет ли блока выше, который не дает родительному блоку слайдера принять нужную ширину? – Chingiz Mamedov 8 дек в 17:43), и слайдер стал responsive.      Так что вероятней всего ошибка в том что код slick slider я размещал не в родительском блоке а в классе wrapper (оберточка).